# Проблема в использование Telegram API javascript

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте! Пишу простого Telegram-бота на javascript. Использую Telegram API. Помогите с методом getUserProfilePhoto. Хочу получить, и отправить человеку его же фото с профиля. Вот код:

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var token = '**************************************';
var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', function (msg) {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    var userId = msg.from.id;
    var userFirstName = msg.from.first_name;
    var userLastName = msg.from.last_name;
    var userPhoto = bot.getUserProfilePhoto(userId,1,1,1);

    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Your id = " + userId, {caption: "I'm a    bot!"});
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Your first name = " + userFirstName,  {caption: "I'm a bot!"});
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Your last name = " + userLastName, {caption: "I'm a bot!"});
    bot.sendPhoto(chatId, userPhoto, {caption: "It's your photo!"});


});
```

Comment: Я с телеграмом никогда не работал, но что-то я такого метода в апи не вижу: https://core.telegram.org/methods. Это прослойка на уровне бота используемого вами. И там я такого метода тоже не вижу. Зато я вижу метод с буквой s на конце: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api#TelegramBot+getUserProfilePhotos

Comment: Спасибо что обратили внимание, не внимательно посмотрел...
Добавил туда букву s, получилось:
    var userPhoto = bot.getUserProfilePhotos(userId,1,1,1);

Comment: И выдает ошибку:

Comment: `Unhandled rejection Error: 400 <"ok": false, "error_code" : 400, description": "Bad Request: there is no photo in the request">`

Comment: Вообще как получить фото профиля, его нужно сохранить и потом использовать, или есть другой способ?